# Create Xpath Manually

Tags: xpath, dom4

[I want to create xpath which must contain word "Asia"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrrHe.png)

//div[@id='destination-loadLevel0']/div/ul/li/div/div/span 
    *for Asia
//div[@id='destination-loadLevel0']/div/ul/li[2]/div/div/span
*for Europe
//div[@id='destination-loadLevel0']/div/ul/li[3]/div/div/span 
 *for USA

```
//<div class="col-md-3 level-column column-viewport" id="destination-loadLevel0">


<div class="row">
<ul>
<li class="col-md-3 col-hotspot unselectable-text" data-parent-group-id="" data-groupid="2244604" data-name="Asia;|03|00|00|">
<div class="tile-container">
<div class="image-label" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Asia">
<span class="title ellipsis">Asia</span>
<span class="icon icon-angle-right"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//*[contains(text(),'Asia')]  | //@*[contains(.,'Asia')]/parent::*`

returns all elements whose text contains 'Asia' or whose attribute values contains 'Asia'

Output :

`<li class="col-md-3 col-hotspot unselectable-text" data-parent-group-id="" data-groupid="2244604" data-name="Asia;|03|00|00|" />
<div class="image-label" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Asia" />
<span class="title ellipsis">Asia</span>`

Comment: Its works first time when page load. if i go back to same page its not finding,.please