# Muliple body nodes present in HTML dom, so Selenium fails to find the element in dom

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate an application and that has multiple HTML head and body tags present. Below is the sample provided. I tried all possibility using xpath, id , class etc. It doesn't work for this application alone as it as embedded HTML page inside the DOM. I guess, JavaScript loads the a new HTML page inside the page.

Even-though the XPath works in Chrome browser, when I put it in script and run, it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[text()='Continue'].

How to tackle this problem?

HTML DOM Sample:

```
<html class="UShellFullHeight">
<head>
<style id="antiClickjackStyle" type="text/css">
        body {
            display : none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="UiBody UShellFullHeight" role="application">
    <div id="canvas" class="UShellFullHeight"></div>
    #document
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html id="home" lang="EN">
       <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       </head>
       <body>
          .
          .
          .
     <span id="WD8A-cnt" class="urNoUserSelect lsButton--contentlsControl--centeraligned  urBtnCnt" style="pointer-events:none;">
          <span class="lsButton__text " id="WD8A-caption" style="white-space:nowrap;">Continue</span>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IMO while truncating the _HTML_ you have chopped off the relevant useful `<tags>` from the _HTML_.

Comment: Yes i did purposily  for making the thing crisp. I hope, this is understandable. If not, help me what else is required here

Comment: Thanks Guys. I got the answer anyways

Answer (score 2):

try with tag:

```
//span[text()='Continue']
```

or

the best solution for this example is to use id, this element has id:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("WD8A-caption"));
```

Or this xpath which is the same

```
//span[@id='WD8A-caption']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath by creating manually 
[Create Xpath Manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482315/create-xpath-manually) or

the element has id and also class name  `driver.findElement(By.className("lsButton__text "))`

Comment: I tried all possibility using id , xpath, class. It is not working especially to this application as it as embedded HTMLpage inside the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your time guys. I got the answer myself.
Answer is i need to switch the frame and do the operation on elements.

to switch frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("id");
```